# Java paintComponents not painting shapes

Tags: java

making a simple Swing GUI app that lets the user pick a shape, pick the length of one side of shape via a JSlider, app then calculates the area/perimeter and paints shape to the screen but i can not seem to get it to paint the shape. what am i missing or doing wrong?

sorry for the poor coding standards, this is just a draft and will be planning to rewrite when i get it working also ignore the automated code.

first class, MyFrame. this is just a JFrame that lets the user pick circle, square and triangle via JMenu.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
                 implements ActionListener {

MyShape circle, square, shape,  triangle;
MyControlPanel panel;

float area, perimeter;

public MyFrame() {
    //initComponents();
    panel = new MyControlPanel();
    panel.setOpaque(true);

    this.setSize(800,800);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());        
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menuShape = new JMenu("Shape");

    panel.getDimension();

    JMenuItem menuItemSquare = new JMenuItem("Square");
    menuItemSquare.addActionListener(this);

    JMenuItem menuItemTriangle = new JMenuItem("Triangle");
    menuItemTriangle.addActionListener(this);

    JMenuItem menuItemCircle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
    menuItemCircle.addActionListener(this);


    menuShape.add(menuItemSquare);
    menuShape.add(menuItemTriangle);
    menuShape.add(menuItemCircle);

    menuBar.add(menuShape);

    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);



    //this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String event = e.getActionCommand();

//not too sure if the standard is to use a switch or if statements?    
    switch(event)
    {
        case "Circle":
            circle = new Circle();
            panel.sendShape(circle, event);
            panel.setSlider(50);
            break;

        case "Square":
            square = new Square();
            panel.sendShape(square, event);
            panel.setSlider(50);
            break;

        case "Triangle":
            triangle = new Triangle();
            panel.sendShape(triangle, event);
            panel.setSlider(50);
            break;
    }

}

public float getArea()
{
    return area;
}

public float getPerimeter()
{
    return perimeter;
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */

    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

next class MyControlPanel, holds the JSlider, two JTextFields and an instance of the Canvas class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class MyControlPanel extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {

static final int MIN = 0;
static final int MAX = 100;
static final int INIT = 50;

MyShape circle, square, triangle;

Canvas graphicPane;
JSlider lengthSlider;
JFormattedTextField pField, aField;

String menuSelection;
int sliderValue;
float size;


private MyShape shape;


public MyControlPanel() {
    //initComponents();

    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    this.setLayout(layout);


    graphicPane = new Canvas();

    this.add(graphicPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    lengthSlider = new JSlider();

    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(numberFormat);
    formatter.setMinimum(new Float(MIN));
    formatter.setMaximum(new Float(MAX));

    pField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
    pField.setValue(new Float(INIT));
    pField.setColumns(5); //get some space


    aField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
    aField.setValue(new Float(INIT));
    aField.setColumns(5); //get some space

    JLabel sliderLabel = new JLabel("Shape Dimension");
    JLabel pLabel = new JLabel("Boundary Lenght = ");
    JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Area = ");

    lengthSlider.setMaximum(100);
    lengthSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    lengthSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
    lengthSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
    lengthSlider.addChangeListener(this);



    this.add(lengthSlider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(sliderLabel);

    this.add(pLabel);
    this.add(pField);

    this.add(aLabel);
    this.add(aField);

    graphicPane.setVisible(true);
    graphicPane.setOpaque(true); 
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{

    // again not to sure if this can be a switch or does it have to be a if statement?
    try{            
        switch(menuSelection)
        {
            // could i put the setAField and setPField out side of the switch?
            case "Circle":
                //shape = new Circle
                float area = circle.getArea(getSliderValue());
                float perimeter = circle.getBoundaryLength(getSliderValue());
                this.setAfield(String.valueOf(area));
                this.setPfield(String.valueOf(perimeter));
                graphicPane.setLength(sliderValue);
                break;

            case "Square":
                area =  square.getArea(getSliderValue());
                perimeter =  square.getBoundaryLength(getSliderValue());
                this.setAfield(String.valueOf(area));
                this.setPfield(String.valueOf(perimeter));
                graphicPane.setLength(sliderValue);
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "area: " + area + " perimeter: " + perimeter);
                break;

            case "Triangle":
                area = triangle.getArea(getSliderValue());
                perimeter = triangle.getBoundaryLength(getSliderValue());
                this.setAfield(String.valueOf(area));
                this.setPfield(String.valueOf(perimeter));
                graphicPane.setLength(sliderValue);
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "area: " + area + " perimeter: " + perimeter);
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "you broke it");
                break;
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe)
    {
        if (sliderValue == 0)
        {
            sliderValue = 50;
        }
        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "you broke it "
                     + "error code: "+ npe);
           //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "area: " + area + " perimeter: " + perimeter);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "you broke it "
                     + "error code: "+ ex);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "area: " + area + " perimeter: " + perimeter);
    }
}

public float getDimension()
{
    return size;
}

public void sendShape(MyShape aShape, String pickedItem)
{
    menuSelection = pickedItem;

    switch(menuSelection)
    {
        case "Circle":
            circle = aShape;
            //graphicPane.setShape(pickedItem);
            // or try
            graphicPane.setShape("Circle");
            break;

        case "Square":
            square = aShape;
            //does it have to be "Square" or will it work this way?
            graphicPane.setShape(pickedItem);
            break;

        case "Triangle":
            triangle = aShape;
            graphicPane.setShape(pickedItem);
            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "you broke it");
    }

}

public void setSlider(int value)
{
    lengthSlider.setValue(value);
}

public int getSliderValue()
{
    sliderValue = lengthSlider.getValue();
    return sliderValue;
}

public void setPfield(String input)
{
    pField.setText(input);
}

public void setAfield(String input)
{
    aField.setText(input);
}




/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

last class Canvas, holds paintComponents

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Canvas extends JPanel{

private String selectedShape = "";
private int dimension = 0;

public Canvas(){
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Shapes"));
    this.setBackground(Color.green);
    this.setOpaque(true);

} 
@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    switch(selectedShape)
    {   //again what is the coding standards, should it be a switch or if?
        case "Circle":
            g.setColor(Color.RED); //trying anything to make it draw
            g.drawOval(50, 50, dimension, dimension);
            repaint();
            g.fillOval(50, 50, dimension, dimension);
            this.repaint();
            break;

        case "Square":
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            //square = new Rectangle(10, 10, dimension, dimension);
            g.drawRect(50, 50, dimension, dimension);
            repaint();
            g.fillRect(50, 50, dimension, dimension);
            this.repaint();
            break;

        case "Triangle":
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            int[] xCoOrd = {50, 50, 50+dimension};
            int[] yCoOrd = {50, 50+dimension, 50+dimension};
            //triangle = new Polygon (xCoOrd, yCoOrd, 3);
            g.drawPolygon(xCoOrd, yCoOrd, 3);
            repaint();
            g.fillPolygon(xCoOrd, yCoOrd, 3);
            this.repaint();
            break;

        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "you broke it");
            repaint();
            this.repaint();
            break;
    }
    repaint();
    this.repaint();      
}

public void setShape(String newShape)
{
    selectedShape = newShape;
}

public void setLength(int newLength)
{
    dimension = newLength;
}

}
```

thanks in advanced.

Comment: TLDR; You need to do a bit more work on isolating the problem. Either run in a debugger or add some prints to figure out which bits of code are being missed...

Comment: no, not yet. i will read up on how to use the debugger in netbeans

Comment: EDIT: can someone direct me to a good debugger tutorial? as ive been informed that that debugger in netbeans only stopped the programme from crashing but its not crashing, just not painting. Junit was pretty useless as well because its bringing up null pointer exceptions but it does not throw theses when running the whole program

Comment: fixed, i had added a "s" by mistake at the end of paintComponent.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override

```
JComponent.paintComponent(final Graphics g)
```

instead of

```
Container.paintComponents(final Graphics g)
```

They serve two different purposes. And there is no need to call `repaint()`.

**EDIT** - Let me try to clarify this a bit:

Your `Canvas` class extends `JPanel` which extends `JComponent` which extends `Container` ...

As a result, your class inherits all the methods of these classes. Furthermore it is possible to override them to alter their behaviour. You already made use of this mechanism.

Your pitfall simply was to chose the wrong method (certainly due to their very similar names).

Comment: my java book is telling me to use JPanel, my friends example uses JPanel and it works. but thanks for your input, if I can not resolve the issue at all then i will use JComponent

Comment: i tried Canvas extends JComponent but still no dice, unless that is not what you mean?

Comment: Simply remove the first `s` in your line `public void paintComponents(Graphics g)`